# I'm stuck in imaging the setup for this problem

Tags: dynamical-systems, classical-mechanics

I have this problem, but I can't seem to figure out the setup of the bead and wire. How does this differ from a problem where the wire is rotating with the axis being the vertical diameter? What is the significance of the fixed point O in this case? Any hints on where to start? Thanks.[image]

Comment: "How does this differ from a problem where the wire is rotating with the axis being the vertical diameter?" - a) what is "the vertical diameter"? b) do you understand that all elements of the picture lie in the same (horizontal) plane, including $O$?

Comment: Okay, its starting to make more sense now that I can see everything lies in the same plane. I dont understand the significance of the length b then, couldn't O be anywhere on the line OC and result in the same problem?

Comment: Point $C$ moves at velocity $\omega b$ with acceleration $\omega^2b$; point $P$ for fixed $\theta$ moves at velocity $\omega \sqrt{b^2+a^2+2ac\cos \theta}$. Looks like $b$ is significant.

Comment: I think I'm missing essential points here :(, why is C moving if it is on the axis of rotation?

Comment: @Abstraction, Maybe, we can imagine $O$ as the Sun, $C$ the earth and $P$ the Moon :)

Comment: Nobody says it is. Axis of rotation intersects our plane in $O$ and everything rotates around it, including the circular wire with centre $C$, distance $|OC|$ remaining constant and equal $b$ through means unknown. ("Moon" idea is slightly dubious since unlike the moon, our bead doesn't gravitate towards $C$ and, as the solution shows, in the end behaves quite differently.)

Comment: okay!! I thought the axis was the line from O to C, hence my confusion. So to obtain the answer to a) would I need to use Newtons 2nd Law on the bead?

Comment: The picture you are linked seems to indicate you have to use a non intertial reference frame approach, if so, you have to consider the centrifugal force (I think you can simply drop the Coriolis force because, relative to the rotating frame, doesn't accelerate the bead)

Comment: So from this I can get to:
$$ma=F-m(\frac{d\omega}{dt})\land y-m\omega\land(\omega\land y)-mA$$
where $y$ is the vector from C to P and $A$ is the acceleration of C (ie $\omega^2b$)
not sure how to incorporate theta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not complicated with the simplification the given solution implies. The exact solution is, with $\tan\alpha=\dfrac{a\sin\theta}{b+a\cos\theta}$ this:

$$-m\omega^2\sqrt{b^2+a^2+2ab\cos \theta}\sin(\theta-\alpha)=m\ddot\theta a$$

With:

$\sqrt{b^2+a^2+2ab\cos \theta}$ being the distance from $O$ to $P$ (where the bead is, of course),

$m\omega^2\sqrt{b^2+a^2+2ab\cos \theta}$ being the centrifugal force acting on the bead,

$m\omega^2\sqrt{b^2+a^2+2ab\cos \theta}\sin(\theta-\alpha)$ being the projection of this force on the tangent to the circular wire the bead is and

$m\ddot\theta a$ is the bead's acceleration along the wire.

Explanation and simplification:

The centrifugal force acts in the direction of the line passing by $O$ and $P$ and outwards (the name is descriptive: centrifugal, latin for fleeing from the center). A simple diagram of forces will make it clear that the centrifugal force times the sinus of $\theta-\alpha$ accelerates the bead along the circular wire. The Coriolis force is of no influence here because it's always orthogonal to the velocity, so is always orthogonal to the path the bead is forced to follow.

You can get the given solution if it's the case that $b\gt\gt a$.

> Being $b\gt\gt a$. We have that $\alpha\approx 0$ and $\sqrt{b^2+a^2+2ab\cos \theta}\approx\sqrt{b^2}=b$
>
>  Leading to $-m\omega^2b\sin\theta=m\ddot\theta a$ and finally to
>
> $\omega^2\dfrac ba\sin\theta+\ddot\theta=0$

Comment: Thank you very much, I can follow almost all of it apart from a few small questions. 1) How did you get $m\ddot \theta a$ as the beads acceleration?
2)I thought you said the normal reaction will be the force causing the bead to accelerate?
3)I'm guessing your $\alpha$ is angle $COP$?

Comment: $m\ddot\theta a$ is the [tangential acceleration](http://physics.tutorvista.com/motion/tangential-acceleration.html), so is, along the path if you are given the angular acceleration. Remember: angular velocity times the radius is the magnitude of the velocity and the angular acceleration times the radius is the magnitude of the tangential acceleration. Yes, $\alpha$ is that angle, the greater $b$, the smaller $\alpha$.